Cannot Download CiviCRM 5.69.6
I am trying to download CiviCRM 5.69.6 to get to the secure version of 5.69.

The release page goes to a 404. I am unable to download this version with Composer as well.  Composer returns.

- Root composer.json requires civicrm/civicrm-core 5.69.6 (exact version match: 5.69.6 or 5.69.6.0), found civicrm/civicrm-core[dev-custom-data-checkbox-fix, ..., dev-4.7.31-rc, 4.6.alpha1, ..., 4.7.31, 5.0.0, ..., 5.76.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint.


Any help is greatly appreciated.

5.69.6 is only available to ESR customers, however note that the next time there is a security release 5.75 will be the new ESR version and there will be no more 5.69 updates, so you may wish to upgrade to 5.75 now instead, especially if you're not an ESR customer.
If you are an ESR customer,

make sure you're signed in to lab.civicrm.org with an account with a current ESR membership. (You can check your account on www.civicrm.org, on your user account page there is a memberships section.)
With composer, you'll need a gitlab token, and note for unrelated reasons gitlab recently expired all tokens, so even if you had one before it might no longer be valid and you'll need a new one which you can generate from lab.civicrm.org.

